# Applicability of Jenkins Plugin VS Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, plugins, command-line-interface

What is the applicability scenarios for developing a Jenkins Plugin VS coding it as a Groovy Script. Both seem to be options for achieving a stage in a pipeline with some tradeoffs.

A bunch of groovy scripts in a repo as shared libraries that can be called from a Jenkins file or a build pipeline is commonly what I see. But there are many plugins that also allow CLI invocation but need to be installed on the Jenkins instance. Is portability and maintenance the only consideration for a script or are there other factors that determine the applicability?